# JS: How to get 'this' while being called by window event

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, event-handling, this, window-object

The self pointer 'this' doesn't work when being called by window global event.

```js
class foo {
    bar(){
        console.log("bar is called");
    }
    
    event_handler(){
        // At the time being called, 'this' here is 'window'
        // instead of instance of foo
        this.bar();
    } 

    init(){
        window.onresize = this.event_handler;
    }
}

var inst = new foo();
inst.init();
```

How to get the correct `this` in the method `event_handler`?

Comment: You can bind the `this`: `window.onresize = this.event_handler.bind(this)`

Comment: @NickParsons tks, that bind function is useful